# What would be an appropriate Stack site to ask questions about choosing a web-host based on my needs?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I really don't know what more detail to add that isn't in the question itself, really.

Just that I am going to be asking questions like what bandwidth (in general) I should look for (based on details I will convey about the site itself).

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to ask a question about choosing a host based on usage and other factors, you could probably ask at Webmasters (if the question hasn't been asked already).

Comment: Okay, I'll be sure to check if it has been answered, first. Thank you!